# Como Limitar o Envio de Formulários Para Usuários, Por Página?

Tags: php, formulário, joomla

Por favor me perdoem pois eu sou bem leigo ao PHP, mas de vez em quando é o suficiente para me virar onde necessário. Porém agora estou empacado e ficaria muito agradecido se pudessem me dar uma luz.

Eu tenho um código que posso usar no RSForm do Joomla que limita o número de envios que qualquer usuário possa fazer em um devido formulário. Esta parte funciona tranquilamente e como eu quero, limita o envio a um formulário por usuário.

Porém, a minha dúvida é: Já que eu uso este mesmo formulário para o envio em diversas páginas diferentes, como eu faria para limitar o envio dos usuários também levando em conta a página que o usuário está realizando o envio?

O resultado final esperado é que cada usuário possa enviar uma por página onde ele tenha acesso ao formulário!

Tenho esse seguinte código que já limita a um envio por usuário, só preciso que ele também leve em consideração a página:

```
// Define the maximum number of submissions.
$max = 1;

// Get the current logged in user.
$user = JFactory::getUser();

// Get a database connection.
$db   = JFactory::getDbo();
$query   = $db->getQuery(true);

// Setup the query.
$query->select('COUNT('.$db->qn('Username').')')
    ->from($db->qn('#__rsform_submissions'))
    ->where($db->qn('FormId').'='.$db->q($formId))
    ->where($db->qn('Username').'='.$db->q($user->get('username')));
    // You can also count by User ID, just replace the above with:
    // ->where($db->qn('UserId').'='.$db->q($user->get('id')));

$db->setQuery($query);
$counter = $db->loadResult();

if ($counter >= $max){
  $formLayout = 'Sorry, you have reached the maximum number of submissions for this form.';
}
```

Agradeço quem puder ajudar!

---

**EDIT:**

Mais uma informação. Estes formulários estarão sempre em uma página de item K2. Descobri que posso por PHP identificar o ID do item de K2 da página atual assim:

```
$K2Itemid = JRequest::getInt('id');
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a usar esta informação para limitar o envio através do ID do K2? De repente é uma condição a adicionar no código.

Comment: Talvez não seja a solução ideal para o que vc quer, mas pq vc não usa um Módulo de Form de Contato para cada página. Assim vc tem um Form para Contato e outro para "Orçamento" por exemplo. E em vez de controlar por página vc controla por Módulo

Comment: @hugocsl Porque este formulário não será usado para contato ou alguma outra tarefa simples. Ele será usado para criar diferentes itens de K2 dependendo de qual página de item de K2 o usuário se encontra. Digamos que eu tenha uma página que é um item de K2 com o título: "Exemplo 1" e outra com "Exemplo 2" e este mesmo formulário se encontra nas duas. O usuário poderá enviar um novo item K2 em cada apenas uma vez.

Comment: Entendi Leon, o K2 é bem legal, usei na versão do Joomla 2.5 ainda rss. Nesse caso não vou poder te ajudar muito então.